# MIME::Lite and inlined CSS images

Tags: html, perl, email, mime

I have the following code:

```
#!/root/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use MIME::Lite;


my $data =<<"DATA";
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC >
<html>
<head>
<style>

#header {
  background-image: url("cid:background.png");
}
</style>


</head>
<body>
<div id="header"></div>
<img src="cid:logo_header.png"></img>
</body>
</html>

DATA

my $msg = MIME::Lite->new(
         To      => 'xxx@xxx.com',
         Subject => 'title',
         Type    => 'text/html',
         Data    => $data
    );
    $msg->attach(
        Type => 'image/png',
        Id   => 'logo_header.png',
        Path => 'logo_header.png',
    );
   $msg->attach( Type => 'image/png',
                 Id   => 'background.png',
                 Path => 'background.png'); 
   $msg->send();
```

Seems like it doesn't display the image inside the CSS (does this module even parses non HTML tags?) when I place the image as a background or `<img>` it displays it fine.
I even tried turning `background-image: url("cid:background.png");` into `background-image: url("background.png");` but this didn't work as well.

any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll be wanting [CSS::Inliner](https://metacpan.org/module/CSS%3a%3aInliner). Specifically designed for this issue.

There are many limitations of html email clients. If you google around the subject you'll see that they all have their own charming quirks.

Comment: even if the inline (inside the HTML tags) the style it still doesnt work. yet to check the module.

Comment: If you find the HTML to be valid but it still doesn't display in your viewer then you're reduced to (1) hand-building your own HTML messages to see if you can find an incantation that works and/or (2) finding a working message with a background-image and seeing what that does.

Comment: You are definitely going to want CSS::Inliner - I wrote it for exactly this reason.